# trouble with code to change the state of my Edittext when using soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, textwatcher

I have my editText set to height and width of 0dp with this code :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView android:id="@+id/ListView_CallData"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </ListView>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:background="@null"
        android:inputType="phone">
    <!--android:visibility="invisible"-->
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

What I want is the size of the editText to change (the user only sees it when they start to type using the softKeyBoard) but it always stays invisible ; that is, 0 height and 0 width. Here's the code in my MainAcitivity.java.

You will find what I believe is the relevant code between the

```
//RELEVANT CODE STARTS HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

comments, but I'm posting all the code in case it's having some impact I don't know about.

I also tried using `getLayoutParams` but that didn't work either. Thanks for any help.

```
package com.example.chris.sunil_gupta;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.CallLog;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

//ArrayList is an implementation of List.
//ArrayList provides a resizable-array, which means that items can be added and removed from the list. An ArrayList is a
// dynamic data structure so it can be used when there is no upper bound on the number of elements, ideal for the Call
// history. From the other side, a simple Array in java is a static data structure, because the initial size of array cannot be
// changed, so it can be used only when the data has a known number of elements.

//We are making a list called listofphonehistory and we are using CallData as the datasource

    private List<CallData> listofphonehistory = new ArrayList<CallData>();

    //    Context is an abstract class...which means what exactly?
    private Context context = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

//create a ListView object called listview
        ListView listview;

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        context = this;

//initialise the object called listview, it's a ListView object and the exact id it will appear in is called ListView_CallData
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView_CallData);

//        call the function getCallDetails which will sort our number, name, call date, call type, duration
        getCallDetails();

//CustomAdapter is the class we are going to use. We will use it to create CustomAdapter
//objects which will appear in the MainActivity activity, using the listofphonehistory
        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, listofphonehistory);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

//        //RELEVANT CODE STARTS HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

        //    This ensures that the editText textbox will have the focus when the activity loads
        // so that our soft keyboard pops up. editText is set to 0dp in width and height,
        //so the user can't see it unless they need to use it. When the user starts typing
        //with the keyboard then the width and height will be bigger and they can see it.
        final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText.requestFocus();

        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        if (editText.length() > 0) {

            //Your query to fetch Data
//            editText.getLayoutParams().width=32;
//            editText.getLayoutParams().height=50;
            editText.setWidth(32);
            editText.setHeight(50);
        }
            }
        });

        //RELEVANT CODE ENDS HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

    }

    public void getCallDetails() {


        //        cursor1 gets all the items in the calllog and arranges them from newest call down
        Cursor cursor1 = getContentResolver().query(
                CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC");

//looks like all the cell values in the calllog database are integers
        int number = cursor1.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
        int type = cursor1.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
        int date = cursor1.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
        int duration = cursor1.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);

        int name = cursor1.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME);

//declare some new variables here; we're going to convert the integers into these
        int callType;
        String phoneNumber;
        String callDate;
        String callDuration;
        Date callDateTime;

        String cachedName;


        while (cursor1.moveToNext()) {
//        go through all the rows in the db and convert the values to strings or whatever
//        It's important that these are inside the while loop. Otherwise it will try to read
//        the value of a column while the cursor is at an invalid position (-1) because moveToNext()
//        hasn't been called yet.

            callType = cursor1.getInt(type);
            phoneNumber = cursor1.getString(number);
            callDate = cursor1.getString(date);
            callDateTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
            callDuration = cursor1.getString(duration);

            cachedName = cursor1.getString(name);


// If the contact has a name, then show the name in the calllog instead of the number
            if (cachedName != null) {
                phoneNumber = cachedName;
            } else {
                phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
            }

//            the string cType will give us text of either outgoing, incoming or missed calls
            String cType = null;


//          callType will either be 1,2 or 3
            switch (callType) {
                case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                    cType = "OUTGOING";
                    break;

                case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                    cType = "INCOMING";
                    break;

                case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                    cType = "MISSED";
                    break;
            }
//          CallData is a constructor
//            We are passing the values cType, phoneNumber, callDateTime and callDuration, in the While Loop of above,
//              to the CallData object and this will show us calltype, callnumber, calldatetime and callduration in our cells.
            CallData calldata = new CallData(cType, phoneNumber, callDateTime, callDuration);
//            add new call data info to the list, moving on down through the values in Calllog
            listofphonehistory.add(calldata);
        }

        cursor1.close();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, this worked for me. The important part missing is :

```
editText.requestLayout();
```

Which basically tells my app to implement my new layout, which consists of a edittext with changed dimensions. When there's nothing in my edittext, I don't want it to be visible. When the user types in my edit text, I want it to be visible. Here's my code :

```
    @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                if (editText.length() > 0) {

                    float density=getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
// I have width set to fill_parent in my xml file
                    editText.getLayoutParams().height =(int)(50*density);
                    editText.requestLayout();



                }
                else if (editText.length() == 0){

                    float density=getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

                    editText.getLayoutParams().height =(int)(0*density);
                    editText.requestLayout();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about trying to change the visibility  in the following method:

```
 @Override
 public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){

 }
```

just changing the visibility of the `textView`? if I understood you right, this should work... good luck

Comment: The thing is I need to show the softkeyboard as soon as the activity starts. The way that is done is by giving the focus to the edittext. An object can't have the focus if it invisible, which is the way it would have to be if I don't want user to see the edittext when the activity starts(using your invisible/ visible suggestion) .Know if I can do it within my piece of code?

Comment: you can try with setting up the softKey in the onCreate Method, setting it to be shown